# Changing the background image for only part of a table

Tags: html, css, html-table

I am trying to change the background image for only part of the table, specifically the first two td elements and leave the third unchanged. I've tried wrapping the first two td in a div and changing the background image of the div but that didn't work.

I've look around elsewhere on the site and I couldn't seem to find anything similar to this question. Here is the code I have:

```
<div height='200px' width='600px'>
  <table width='100%' style='display: inline-block; float: left; border-collapse: collapse; background-image: url(http://image.em.insightvacations.com/lib/fe8e1570706c037e7c/m/2/f1501c18-c3db-4fcd-818b-45d6199cc2e0.jpg'>
    <tr>
      <td width='33%' style='vertical-align: top; padding: 20px'><img src="http://image.em.insightvacations.com/lib/fe8e1570706c037e7c/m/2/1c64a1a7-519b-406a-8f29-6944c179a86f.png" alt="Anniversery badge"> </td>
      <td align='left' width='33%' style="color: white; font-family: 'Effra', Monterrat, sans-serif; font-size: 25px; line-height: 22px; padding: 20px; background-color: rgba(166, 208, 237, 0.65); font-weight: bold">GLORIES OF GREECE<br><br><br>
        <font style="font-family: 'Effra', Monterrat, sans-serif; font-size: 16px; line-height: 15px;"> 8 days <br>
          <div align='center'> <button> EXPLORE NOW </button> </div>
        </font>
      </td>
      <td width='34%' align='left' bgcolor="#081e3f" style="color: white; font-family: 'Effra', Monterrat, sans-serif; font-size: 16px; line-height: 1.5; padding: 20px">This popular journey covers a multitude of noteworhty ancient sitesm majestic monuments and mystical monasteries</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: at a first glimpse, font tag is not supported in HTML5. Do not use it. Second, why use tables and not `flexbox` for eg ?

Comment: Oh sorry I didn't mention this, I am coding in html4 because this is for emails

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap there two tds into table and apply background to table.

Codepen [demo](https://codepen.io/3rdthemagical/pen/KBzwad?editors=1000).

```html
<div height='200px' width='600px'>
    <table width='100%' style='display: inline-block; float: left; border-collapse: collapse;'>
        <tr>
            <td width='66%' style='background-image: url(http://image.em.insightvacations.com/lib/fe8e1570706c037e7c/m/2/f1501c18-c3db-4fcd-818b-45d6199cc2e0.jpg'>
                <table width='100%'>
                    <tr>
                        <td width="50%" style="vertical-align: top; padding: 20px;">
                            <img src="http://image.em.insightvacations.com/lib/fe8e1570706c037e7c/m/2/1c64a1a7-519b-406a-8f29-6944c179a86f.png" alt="Anniversery badge">
                        </td>
                        <td align='left' width='50%' style="color: white; font-family: 'Effra', Monterrat, sans-serif; font-size: 25px; line-height: 22px; padding: 20px; background-color: rgba(166, 208, 237, 0.65); font-weight: bold">
                            GLORIES OF GREECE
                            <br>
                            <br>
                            <br>
                            <font style="font-family: 'Effra', Monterrat, sans-serif; font-size: 16px; line-height: 15px;">
                                8 days <br>
                                <div align='center'> <button> EXPLORE NOW </button> </div>
                            </font>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </td>
            <td width='34%' align='left' bgcolor="#081e3f" style="color: white; font-family: 'Effra', Monterrat, sans-serif; font-size: 16px; line-height: 1.5; padding: 20px">This popular journey covers a multitude of noteworhty ancient sitesm majestic monuments and mystical monasteries</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Ah! That's it! I can't believe I didn't think about that!